# .htaccess permalinks: which rewrite rule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all users from `mysite.com/username` to `mysite.com/user.php?user=username`

I am now using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/ user.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/.]+) user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

It works, but it is also redirecting directory paths into `user.php` (Ex. `mysite.com/css/style.css` -> `mysite.com/user.php?user=css/style.css`).

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to skip requests for real files and directories like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/?$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteCond` to exclude requests ending in `.css`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/? user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

I combined your 2 rules into one using a question mark `?` to make the trailing forward slash optional.

If you so desire you can also exclude other "helper" files. And it might be helpful to also exclude re-rewriting the request for resource *user.php*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !user.php$
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/? user.php?user=$1 [L]
```